# If $\left(e^{y^2}-\csc y\csc^2x\right)dx+\left(2xye^{y^2}-\csc y\cot y\cot x\right)dy=0$ is exact, then solve

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If the equation is exact, solve:

$$( e^{y^2} - \csc y \csc^2 x ) dx + (2xye^{y^2} - \csc  y \cot y \cot x ) dy= 0  $$

Solution:Let the equation be cast as
$ p(x,y)dx+q(x,y)dy=0$ where we have

$p(x,y)=e^{y^2} - \csc  y \csc^2 x$

$q(x,y)=2xye^{y^2} - \csc  y \cot  y \cot x$

$\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}=2ye^{y^2}+\cot(y)\csc(y)\csc^2(x)$

$\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial x}=2ye^{y^2}+\cot(y)\csc(y)\csc^2(x)$

Both partials coincide and therefore it is exact.

Now to find the solution $u(x,y)= cte$

$u(x,y)=\displaystyle\int p(x,y)dx=\displaystyle\int (e^{y^2} - \csc  y \csc^2 x)dx=xe^{y^2}+\csc(y)\cot(x)+h(y)$

how to conclude with this exercise imposing

$\dfrac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=q(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

But then
$$
q(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}  = q(x,y) + h'(y)
$$
and so $h$ is constant.

Comment: can you please tell me the solution
of this exercise step by step?

Comment: You are trying to find $u$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=p$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = q$. You solved the first, obtaining $u(x,y)=xe^{y^2} + \csc(y)\cot(x)+h(y)$. But then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = q(x,y)+h'(y)$, and hence $h'(y)=0$, so $h$ is constant. Thus the solution is $u(x,y)=xe^{y^2} + \csc(y)\cot(x)+c$ for a constant $c$. This method words because the derivative is exact.